# Fade entire div except for one span with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have HTML in the following structure:

```
<div class="mediaItem">
    <a class="articleLink" target="_blank" href="http://foo.com"></a>
    <span class="articleSummary">Summary</span>
    <span class="sourceDate">Source</span>
    <span class="remove"></span>
</div>
```

This html repeats itself a number of times.

I would like to fade the entire contents of the current "mediaItem" div on mouseover, except for the "remove" span, which needs to remain at an opacity of 1.

Here is the Jquery code I have so far:

```
$(".mediaItem").live({
    mouseenter:
         function(){
             $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
         },
    mouseleave:
         function(){
             $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
         }
    });
```

I have tried many combinations of selecting the entire div except for the "remove" span, but I cannot seem to get it to work with only the current "mediaItem."  How can I fade everything in the "mediaItem" that is currently hovered over without effecting the "remove" span?

Comment: Can't you just set display:none using css for that span?

Comment: I want the span displayed but just not effected by the fading.

Comment: You cannot achieve this functionality by keeping the remove span inside mediaItem div. If you want you have to keep the span outside and position it absolutely on top of mediaItem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$(this).children(":not('.remove')").fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
```

Comment: (but doesnt mean mine should be downvoted, mine still technically answers the problem)

Comment: Exactly what I need.  I wasn't using :not syntax correctly. Thanks for showing me.

Answer (score 5):

how about using a different selector?

```
$('.mediaItem > *:not(.remove)').fade*()
```

Select all children, but exempt the remove child.

Comment: I do like the children reference better though. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can fade each child element individually. This is how I would do it:

```
$(".mediaItem").live({
    mouseenter:
         function(){
             $(this).children('.articleSummary').fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
             $(this).children('.sourceDate').fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
             $(this).children('.articleLink').fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
         },
    mouseleave:
         function(){
             $(this).children('.articleSummary').fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
             $(this).children('.sourceDate').fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
             $(this).children('.articleLink').fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
         }
    });
```

Comment: jQuery's `not` pseudo-selector exists for a reason: you never KNOW what else is there. Maybe stuff was ajax-loaded in!

Comment: Why the downvote? For the sample data, this will work just fine. It is not easily changed, but it will work. Granted that a specific selector would be a better option.

Comment: @Nate: That is just it. I don't deny that it will work, but it is like using a sledgehammer to hang a picture. However, in the spirit of equality, I re-read the question, and see that he does mention that this HTML should be fairly static format so I'll un-downvote.

Comment: Agreed. This is not the best answer, but I'm guessing (can't think of any off the top of my head) there are situations where something like this could be more effective.